What are limitations of try catch preventing the rollback in code in TRY block and within a stored procedure, in the presence of xact abort on?

You may argue that the line
IF @@trancount > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION is not needed if there no
explicit transaction in the procedure, but nothing could be more
wrong. Maybe you call a stored procedure which starts a transaction,
but which is not able to roll it back because of the limitations of
TRY-CATCH.

Link: https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html
Code provided is:
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_data @a int, @b int AS 
   SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON
   BEGIN TRY
      BEGIN TRANSACTION
      INSERT sometable(a, b) VALUES (@a, @b)
      INSERT sometable(a, b) VALUES (@b, @a)
      COMMIT TRANSACTION
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
      IF @@trancount > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
      DECLARE @msg nvarchar(2048) = error_message()  
      RAISERROR (@msg, 16, 1)
      RETURN 55555
   END CATCH

Since SET XACT_ABORT is ON, and if instead of insert there was a stored procedure execution, and say we didn't have the following:
IF @@trancount > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION


What are the limitations of TRY-CATCH that would prevent the rollback within the other stored procedure, even in the presence of SET XACT_ABORT ON?

Why isn't the rollback happening in this stored procedure for an error in the underlying stored procedure given that SET XACT_ABORT is ON?



"Why isn't the rollback happening in this stored procedure..." We need an [mre] to answer that. Though you are asking two questions here; one would hope you know that questions should ask one specific question (unless the 2 are very closely related, which they don't appear to be here).

It appears you've already had an answer to some of this in the past.

IMO Sommarskog is wrong about this, as I said on that dba.se answer. There is no possible way for the transaction to not roll back if XACT_ABORT is ON, and RAISERROR is a bad idea as well, because it only allows one error message and raises the wrong error level. The argument about compilation errors is ridiculous: if your code doesn't compile then it's not code, just nonsense.
